# Finding an Install of OpenGL for 64 Bit Windows

Tags: opengl, windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to get started on opengl programming from the videotutorialsrock.com site.
It wants me to install GLUT and the OpenGL SDK. I was able to download GLUT successfully but the link he has on this page
http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/opengl_tutorial/get_opengl_setup_windows/text.php
does not work on my 64 bit Windows 7 install.

I tried going to the OpenGL page and did not find a download.
I am not very familiar with OpenGL just yet so I am hesitant to just download some OpenGL library and go from there.

What should I download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .DLL will already be installed as part of Windows

The .LIB file can be found in the Windows Platform SDK ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=484269E2-3B89-47E3-8EB7-1F2BE6D7123A&displaylang=en )

If you're using MinGW instead of Visual Studio, the .a (.lib equivalent) should have been installed with the rest of MinGW.

The following blog post may also prove helpful:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=484269E2-3B89-47E3-8EB7-1F2BE6D7123A&displaylang=en

Comment: The example is now running successfully. I put the glut.lib and glut.dll file in the project directory and included the glut files in VS C++ 2008 in the include directories. 

The SDK path is already included with the default options of the VS C++ 2008 IDE so I guess that was all it took.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install OpenGL, it's part of Windows. For GLUT just get the source code of freeglut and compile it as a 64bit lib.

Comment: Do I not need a lib library for the OpenGLSDK? He points the path variable to it.

Comment: There also seems to be a OpenGLSDK/include directory I need as well.

Comment: Well, you need to link to the OpenGL32.lib wich is part of the Windows SDK.
The WindowsSDK contains everything you need to start with OpenGL programming, except for GLUT.

Comment: Take a look at this. It is a bit outdated but it will give you some of the basics...
http://www.glprogramming.com/red/

Comment: Really all you need to do is include the OpenGL headers (or GLUT headers) and link to the OpenGL32.lib.