# Where to get OpenGL 2.0 for windows 7 64bit

Tags: opengl, graphics, windows-7

I've been looking for OpenGL version 2.0 or higher, but I haven't found anything I could use so far. There is no download section on the official website and google finds mostly stuff like OpenGL Viewer or OpenGL Screen Saver, but I am looking for OpenGL to develop games/graphics/vizualizations ( precisely version 2.0, but I know that higher versions are also compatible with 2.0 then they are also OK ). Could someone please give me a source, which I could get appropriate OpenGL for my project from? I've managed only to download one, but it didn't work, because it was created for 32bit OS, and I use 64bit windows 7. Does anyone know how to handle this problem as well?

this is my graphic card : NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GS

Comment: Possible dup: [Finding an Install of OpenGL for 64 Bit Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805766/finding-an-install-of-opengl-for-64-bit-windows). See also: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Windows

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to download an SDK to use OpenGL in 64-bit applications on Windows. All you need is a 64-bit capable compiler, and the Windows Platform SDK (which comes bundled with Microsoft Visual Studio).

But there is a catch: Microsoft's OpenGL implementation hasn't been updated since OpenGL 1.1, and to use functionality from later versions OpenGL, you need to use OpenGL-extensions. Luckily, [some nice people](http://glew.sourceforge.net/credits.html) has made [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), a library that does the extension-work for you and allows you to simply compile OpenGL 2.0 (and later, as GLEW is updated) source code for Windows. Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok I will download MVS and that GLEW library and see if that works. Thanks for help.

Comment: Khronos makes GLEW?  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was somehow confused by it being available under the [Khronos license](http://glew.sourceforge.net/khronos.txt), which says "Copyright (c) 2007 The Khronos Group Inc."

Answer (score 1):

kusma is completely right, but maybe you'll need more precise directions.

First you'll need OpenGL libraries. These will be given with your Visual Studio / mingw / whatever installation.

Then you'll need to create an OpenGL window. You can do it with windows functions, but it is a nightmare. You should go for something like GLFW.

Then you'll need something to deal with openGL extensions ( as kusma said, you don't want OpenGL 1.1 only ). Use GLEW.

You will also need some math stuff : create a vector ( on the C++ side ), compute your projection matrix... GLM can do that for you.

Last but not least, you may want to use Cg for your shaders (but you can use GLSL instead, which is "built-in" in OpenGL)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the OpenGL SDK site. [LINK](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/) Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Well I haven't used it before so I don't know at all which package I should choose. This one "OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)" looks good, but I am not 100% sure if this is the right one. Anyway thanks for the link I will try GLM.

Comment: GLM is not what you want (although it may be useful at some point - it replaces the deprecated matrix stack functionality from early OpenGL versions). As others pointed out, what you want is a mechanism to access extensions such as GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to tell is if your using glBegin/glEnd statements you using old context methods (good for quick demos and prototyping, bad if your looking to do something that needs to look professional).  When you start dealing with opengl topics that cover buffers and hint to VBO- vertex buffer objects and FBOs - Frame buffer objects your in the area of more modern opengl methods.  If you want to get up to speed in the shortest amount of time, start with buffers and keep working your way forward.  Just remember when your dealing with device contexts (methods to create your windows) if you stick with OGL 2.1 or lower your limiting yourself ( Think roughly DirectX9/early DirectX10) . Your video card handles DirectX10 and OpenGL 3. Best bet start there. Check out NVidia's developer site, http://developer.nvidia.com/ And, take a look at http://opengl.org site check out the forums - http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards, the guys there are helpful (be careful not to re-post old questions).

Also check out http://swiftless.com - its a good start - and he labels his tutorials by ogl versions.

Comment: Your first sentence is completely wrong.  VBOs were standardized in OpenGL 1.5 and display lists long before that.